# VSCode cannot access Docker image inside wsl2 image

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I am running a cuda enabled docker container inside wsl2 and when i try to use VSCode to run scripts inside it i cannot connect to it. The message in the docker plugin window is:
`Error: connect EACCESS /var/run/docker.sock`
I added the default user in the wsl to the docker group. I double-checked and i know for sure that i can run docker as a user. How do I elevate the VSCode privillages to make it able to access the docker inside the wsl image?

Btw. I cannot use docker desktop because it does not allow to use the gpu inside the container.

**UPDATE**

So with the set of plugins locally:Docker, Remote - WSL,  Remote - Containers, Remote SSH, Remote Development, Remote SSH - editing configuration files

in the WSL: Docker Explorer, Docker, Docker Extension Pack

I am able to log from VSCode directly to the console and perform other basic operations (starting containers etc). Attaching VSCode is still impossible as for now. At least the menu option under RMB throws an error

Comment: Do you have cuda enabled for wsl? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/gpu-cuda-in-wsl

Comment: yes. the docker container runs with --gpu all with no problem. the only problem is i cannot access it from VSCode and i really really dont want to use vim as my development environment